# Ajax success method handling complex data

Tags: ajax

Here is the method I'm calling:

```
public Bear GetBear(int bearId)
    {
        MyEntities be = new MyEntities ();
        Location bear = (from b in be.Bears
                        where b.id == bearId
                        select b).First();
        return bear;
    }
```

Here is how I call it:

```
$.ajax({ url: "Bear/GetBear", data: { bearId: 2}, success: function (bear) { alert(bear.id) } })
```

But, the text in the alerted dialog box is undefined. And when I'm moving through GetBear with breakpoint, the returned bear HAS id. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you convert the data into json/xml/text/dataType (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) before sending it back?

Comment: What would the type of GetBear would be if it returns json?

Comment: I don't think that changes anything in this case, however if he uses contentType, it might.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `$.ajax` call specifying your contentType to JSON.
Also, take a look in this article, it shows exactly what you're looking for.

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Also, note that in this article he uses `msg.d` to get the json.

Comment: but GetBear isn't service method.

Comment: As long as it's accessible, you're fine, you can use those same settings.

Comment: But on the link there isn't the method definition. That is what I need in order to see how to return Json.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that you should change your `$.ajax` by including `type: "POST",  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` like that sample. That should help you to get the returning data as json.

Comment: What else have you tried? are you using any debug tool? have you tried `bear.d.id`? maybe changing `type: "GET"` just in case? Just trying to help out :P